# android center textview in layout

Tags: android

I have a listview with custom rows. In the row there are these items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY">
   </ImageView>"

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textsll"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">          
  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_width="240dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end">"
  </TextView>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" 
    android:layout_width="240dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end">
  </TextView>
  </RelativeLayout>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textsll2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">"
  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" 
    android:layout_width="40dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#87EB81">
  </TextView>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If both textviews has some content, they are centered vertically in the row (almost).

But if the lower textview is empty, I call:

```
            holder.textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Still, the upper textview gets into the top of the row. Why?

[image]

If I set it to View.GONE, I get this, but I dont want the height of the row to change:

[image]

Comment: Then give a specific height to your relative layout and make your TextView GONE

Comment: Look at my updated answer. Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

In a `RelativeLayout`, views are aligned with their parent, with the `RelativeLayout` itself, or with other views. For instance, we declared that the description is aligned with the bottom of the `RelativeLayout` and that the title is positioned above the description and anchored to the parent's top. With the description GONE, `RelativeLayout` doesn't know where to position the title's bottom edge. To solve this problem, you can use a very special layout parameter called [**layout_alignWithParentIfMissing**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_alignWithParentIfMissing).

This `boolean` parameter simply tells `RelativeLayout` to use its own edges as anchors when a constraint target is missing. For instance, if you position a view to the right of a GONE view and set `alignWithParentIfMissing` to true, `RelativeLayout` will instead anchor the view to its left edge. In our case, using `alignWithParentIfMissing` will cause `RelativeLayout` to align the title's bottom with its own bottom.

For more look at [Layout Tricks: Creating Efficient Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html)

Comment: I understand that harc code is the only way. When I set it, the 2nd textview disappears...

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_weight` to set all the childs of the main LinearLayout to mesure the same.

Use a LinearLayout as parent for textView1 and textView2. Use Use `android:layout_weight` to have the same size for each one.

Define TextView one with `android:gravity="center_vertical|left"` Then, if you don't want to show the second TextView, set its visibility as `View.GONE`.

Maybe this will resolve your problem,

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix some value to your RelativeLayout's height like-

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/textsll"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible in your `RelativeLayout` by setting up the `layout_below` and `layout_above` with the help of parent alignment by using `layout_centerInParent` and set the value true of `layout_centerHorizontal`

Hope, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
    <TextView
        ...
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        ... 
        />
```

in your_list_item.xml. And use View.GONE

Comment: This resulted in very high rows. I know this attribute but it is not working  here

Answer (score 0):

To Solve for your problem what u can do is have the LinearLayout fill Parent.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

And use `View.GONE` This will make the Row Height Same.

If you see a gap after **Best Car in World** then try using Relative Layout and align last Layout to bottom.